# How to check if all the upper-case letters are present in the input the user gives?

Tags: c

I'm trying to check if all the upper-case letters are present in the input the user entered.

I tried to make an array of 26 values, 0 will represent A and 25 is Z. At first I initialize the values to 0.

After that I asked the user for input and then I checked if it matches with the ASCII.  If yes, I changed the array value to 1.

After that, I make sure all the array values are 1; if yes all the letters were in the input.

I assume that the user will end the input with 0.

The input is "THE Q$@UICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER tHe LAZY DOG!0".

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int z;
int x = 1;
int arr[26] = {0};

printf("enter a sentance to check if all latter in ABC are in the sentance (in upper case):\n");

while (x!=0) {
    scanf(" %d", &x);
    z = x - 65;
    if (z>=0 && z<=25) {
       arr[z]=1;
    }
}

z=0;
while (arr[z]==1 && z<26) {
    ++z;
    if (z==26) {
        printf("all the ABC in ur sentance\n");
        break;
    }
}

 printf("all the ABC does not in ur sentance\n");

    return 0;
}
```

There is no output and I think it's because there is a problem with the scanf, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Why are you using `%d` in your scanf if the user is entering a string? That's for entering numbers.

Comment: `%d` is for reading integers, not letters like `ABC`. What is your input?

Comment: Do you mean that you are trying to check whether all the letters in the alphabet are present in the input data?  Like with "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" or "Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs" or "The five boxing wizards jump quickly" or "How vexingly quick daft zebras jump"?

Comment: If you want to get the characters codes, use `%c`, not `%d`.

Comment: @Barmar ... and use `char` instead of `int` for `x`

Comment: Why are you using an `int` array to store what seems to be a string? How about: `char arr[100]; fgets(arr,sizeof(arr),stdin); if (strstr(arr,"ABC") != NULL) printf("string has ABC\n");`

Comment: don't use magic numbers like `65`, use the character literal `'A'`.

Comment: @CraigEstey He wants to check that it contains ALL the uppercase letters, not the exact string `ABC`.

Comment: @Barmar I used %d because I wanted the letter become its number from the ASCII

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes

Comment: @MikeCAT the input is "THE Q$@UICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER tHe LAZY DOG!0" i edit the question.

Comment: @AlfaHores That's not what `%d` does, that's what `%c` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `%c` to read a character and convert it to its character code. `%d` reads the representation of an integer.

If the character `0` ends the input, you need to compare with `'0'`, not `0`.

You can use `isupper()` to test if a character is an uppercase letter, rather than testing the range yourself.

The loop to check that all the characters have been entered can be simplified as I've shown below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int z;
    char x;
    int arr[26] = {0};

    printf("enter a sentance to check if all latter in ABC are in the sentance (in upper case):\n");

    while (1) {
        scanf(" %c", &x);
        if (x == '0') {
            break;
        }
        if (isupper(x)) {
            z = x - 'A';
            arr[z]=1;
        }
    }

    for (z = 0; z < 26; z++) {
        if (arr[z] == 0) {
            printf("all the ABC are not in your sentance\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("all the ABC in your sentance\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

- `%d` format specifier in `scanf()` is for reading integers, not characters. In this case, you should use `getchar()` instead of `scanf()` to read characters one-by-one.
- The character `0` don't have the value 0. (it is 48 in ASCII).
- Using magic numbers like `65` is not good. Using character constants like `'A'` should be good in this case to make the meaning clear.

The part

```c
while (x!=0) {
    scanf(" %d", &x);
    z = x - 65;
    if (z>=0 && z<=25) {
       arr[z]=1;
    }
}
```

should be:

```c
while ((x = getchar()) != '0' && x != EOF) {
    z = x - 'A';
    if (z>=0 && z<=25) {
       arr[z]=1;
    }
}
```

Also note that `"all the ABC does not in ur sentance\n"` will be printed even after `"all the ABC in ur sentance\n"` is printed. You should use `return 0;` instead of `break;` to finish the execution of the function and prevent the extra string from being outputted.

Comment: thank a lot! u show me new skills that I dont know. I will try to learn them now!